# Apache Ambari Stale PID error

Tags: apache, postgresql, hadoop, bigdata

I'm running Ambari on a Digital Ocean Droplet.  I've destroyed and reinstalled multiple droplets, including fresh installs of Ambari, and by extension, PostgreSQL.  When trying to start the server I keep running into the error below.  I've restarted the server, re-setup the server, removed the Stale PID File, and many other things, but can't find an answer.

```
[root@jamatney0 ~]# ambari-server status
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Ambari-server status
Ambari Server not running. Stale PID File at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
```

For what it's worth, here's the output of the server log.

```
[root@jamatney0 ~]# cat /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log
17:30:58,957  INFO Configuration:302 - Generation of file with password
17:30:58,992  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:30:58,992  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:30:59,883 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:30:59,884  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:31:00,885  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:31:03,073  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:31:03,073  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:false
17:31:03,073  INFO CertificateManager:137 - Generation of server certificate
17:31:04,082  INFO ShellCommandUtil:43 - Command openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:C0VnwoCRefhMWSNaO3WMz0d6fLAOTeCejX8TdpJYNVt2ZTbtNV -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key 4096  was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
17:31:04,101  INFO ShellCommandUtil:43 - Command openssl req -passin pass:C0VnwoCRefhMWSNaO3WMz0d6fLAOTeCejX8TdpJYNVt2ZTbtNV -new -key /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -batch was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
17:31:04,131  INFO ShellCommandUtil:43 - Command openssl x509 -passin pass:C0VnwoCRefhMWSNaO3WMz0d6fLAOTeCejX8TdpJYNVt2ZTbtNV -req -days 365 -in /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -signkey /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt 
 was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
17:31:04,139  INFO ShellCommandUtil:43 - Command openssl pkcs12 -export -in /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -inkey /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -certfile /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12 -password pass:C0VnwoCRefhMWSNaO3WMz0d6fLAOTeCejX8TdpJYNVt2ZTbtNV -passin pass:C0VnwoCRefhMWSNaO3WMz0d6fLAOTeCejX8TdpJYNVt2ZTbtNV 
 was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
17:31:04,477  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:31:04,487  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:31:04,604 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:31:04,618 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:36:05,998  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:36:06,015  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:36:06,015  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:36:07,075 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:36:07,076  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:36:07,797  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:36:10,035  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:36:10,035  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:36:10,593  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:36:10,603  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:36:10,730 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:36:10,735 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:36:12,938  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:36:12,953  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:36:12,953  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:36:13,819 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:36:13,820  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:36:14,527  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:36:16,755  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:36:16,755  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:36:17,063  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:36:17,076  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:36:17,205 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:36:17,210 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:43:42,135  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:43:42,151  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:43:42,151  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:43:43,029 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:43:43,030  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:43:43,857  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:43:45,810  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:43:45,811  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:43:46,198  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:43:46,207  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:43:46,310 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:43:46,322 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:43:52,686  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:43:52,702  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:43:52,702  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:43:53,518 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:43:53,519  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:43:54,188  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:43:56,497  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:43:56,497  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:43:56,901  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:43:56,910  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:43:57,044 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:43:57,055 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:46:02,312  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:46:02,330  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:46:02,330  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:46:03,258 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:46:03,259  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:46:04,074  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:46:06,332  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:46:06,332  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:46:06,770  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:46:06,779  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:46:07,000 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:46:07,009 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
17:53:17,306  INFO Configuration:315 - Reading password from existing file
17:53:17,323  INFO Configuration:492 - Hosts Mapping File null
17:53:17,323  INFO HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
17:53:18,433 ERROR MasterKeyServiceImpl:109 - Master key is not provided as a System property or an environment varialble.
17:53:18,434  INFO Configuration:394 - Credential provider creation failed.
Master key initialization failed.
17:53:19,331  INFO AmbariServer:447 - Getting the controller
17:53:21,637  INFO CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
17:53:21,637  INFO CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:true
17:53:22,011  INFO AmbariServer:124 - ********* Meta Info initialized **********
17:53:22,022  INFO ClustersImpl:88 - Initializing the ClustersImpl
17:53:22,251 ERROR AmbariServer:457 - Failed to run the Ambari Server
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:57)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.class(BootStrapImpl.java:47)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.performStaticInjection(AmbariServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.run(AmbariServer.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jamatney0: jamatney0
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl.<init>(BootStrapImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.bootstrap.BootStrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$ea3dd8f9.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 4 more
17:53:22,266 ERROR AmbariServer:421 - Error stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.stop(AmbariServer.java:419)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.main(AmbariServer.java:459)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting /var/lib/pgsql and restart ambari server. It worked for me